# Lodash: sorting an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, sorting, lodash

I have an array of arrays of the following kind

`let finalData = [[1920000000, 273.15], [1620033000, 276.15], [1627700000, 272.15]]`

The first value inside the data array is the timestamp. How do I sort the entire array from smallest to largest timestamp, with or without `lodash`?

Expected result:

`let finalData = [[1620033000, 276.15], [1627700000, 272.15], [1920000000, 273.15]]`

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Have you tried `finalData.sort()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```js
const finalData = [[1920000000, 273.15], [1620033000, 276.15], [1627700000, 272.15]];
finalData.sort(([a], [b]) => a - b);

console.log(finalData);
```

Using `lodash`:

```js
let finalData = [[1920000000, 273.15], [1620033000, 276.15], [1627700000, 272.15]];
finalData = _.sortBy(finalData, e => e[0]);

console.log(finalData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```